# iframe pdf render not working on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, iframe, heroku

I have a Rails 4.0.2 application that has an iframe with the source of iframe linked to a pdf on the internet.  The code goes something like

```
%iframe{:src => @document.doc.url, width: '100%', height: '30%'}
```

where @document.doc.url is a url like http://s3.amazonaws.com/controlsafe/board_minutes/docs/000/000/001/original/document.pdf?1388787348#toolbar=0

The weird issue is that this renders the pdf fine on localhost:3000 but not on heroku.  I suspect that this is because we haven't bought any dynos but I'm not 100% sure.

Does anyone have any experience with rendering a pdf on a iframe on heroku?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I found the issue.  It seems that if you have a SSL certificate applied to your url so that it starts with "https://", the media that you're referring to in the iframe has to start with "https://" as well.

Also you have to add this line in your application.rb file

```
config.action_dispatch.default_headers = {
  'X-Frame-Options' => 'ALLOWALL'
}
```

All works fine now :)